# Cant insert old database data to the new one using old php plain

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a old website with a old database and i try to bring the data to my new database. Me and my employees wrote a script to do that but it isn't working properly.

```
<?php

$user = 'homestead';
$pass ='secret';

try {
    $oldDb = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=old_database', $user, $pass);

    $newDb = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=new_database', $user, $pass);

    $newDb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $selectRoles = $newDb->prepare("SELECT * FROM roles");
    $selectRoles->execute();
    $roles = $selectRoles->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

    if (!$roles) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO roles (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('1', 'Student')";
        $newDb->exec($sql);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO roles (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('2', 'Teacher')";
        $newDb->exec($sql);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO roles (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('3', 'Manager')";
        $newDb->exec($sql);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO roles (`id`, `name`) VALUES ('4', 'Admin')";
        $newDb->exec($sql);
    }


    $users = [];

    foreach ($oldDb->query('SELECT id, email, password, name, street, house_number, postcode, role from users') as $row) {

        $userId = $row['id'];
        $street = $row['street'];
        $houseNumber = $row['house_number'];
        $postal_code = $row['postal_code'];

        $row['Address_id'] = $row['id'];
        $row['Profile_id'] = $row['id'];

        if ($row['role'] == 'Student') {
            $row['Role_id'] = '1';
        } elseif ($row['role'] == 'Teacher') {
            $row['Role_id'] = '2';
        } elseif ($row['role'] == 'Manager') {
            $row['Role_id'] = '3';
        } elseif ($row['role'] == 'Admin') {
            $row['Role_id'] = '4';
        }


        $address = $newDb->prepare("INSERT INTO addresses (id, street, house_number, postal_code) VALUES (:id, :street, :house_number, :postal_code)");
        $address->bindParam(':id', $row['id']);
        $address->bindParam(':street', $street);
        $address->bindParam(':house_number', $houseNumber);
        $address->bindParam(':postal_code', $postal_code);
        $address->execute();

        $name = explode(" ", $row['name']);
        $first_name = $name[0];
        $last_name = $name[1];
        $address = $newDb->prepare("INSERT INTO profiles (id, first_name, last_name) VALUES (:id, :first_name, :last_name)");
        $address->bindParam(':id', $row['id']);
        $address->bindParam(':first_name', $first_name);
        $address->bindParam(':last_name', $last_name);
        $address->execute();

        $user = $newDb->prepare("INSERT INTO users (id, email, password, Address_id, Profile_id, Role_id) VALUES (:id, :email, :password, :Address_id, :Profile_id, :Role_id)");
        $user->bindParam(':id', $row['id']);
        $user->bindParam(':email', $row['email']);
        $user->bindParam(':password', $row['password']);
        $user->bindParam(':Address_id', $row['id']);
        $user->bindParam(':Profile_id', $row['id']);
        $user->bindParam(':Role_id', $row['Role_id']);
        $user->execute();
    }

    foreach ($oldDb->query('SELECT id, title, content, Users_id from blog') as $row) {
        $blog = $newDb->prepare("INSERT INTO blogs (id, title, content, User_id) VALUES (:id, :title, :content, :User_id)");
        $blog->bindParam(':id', $row['id']);
        $blog->bindParam(':title', $row['title']);
        $blog->bindParam(':content', $row['content']);
        $blog->bindParam(':User_id', $row['id']);
        $blog->execute();
    }

    foreach ($oldDb->query('SELECT id, author, text, Blog_id from comment') as $row) {
        $name = explode(" ", $row['author']);
        $first_name = $name[0];
        $last_name = $name[1];

        $profile = $newDb->prepare("SELECT id FROM profiles WHERE first_name = :first_name");
        $profile->bindParam(':first_name', $first_name);
        $profile->execute();
        $data = $profile->fetchAll();

        $comment = $newDb->prepare("INSERT INTO comments (id, text, Blog_id, User_id) VALUES (:id, :text, :Blog_id, :User_id)");
        $comment->bindParam(':id', $row['id']);
        $comment->bindParam(':text', $row['text']);
        $comment->bindParam(':Blog_id', $row['Blog_id']);
        $comment->bindParam(':User_id', $data[0]['id']);
        $comment->execute();
    }

    foreach ($oldDb->query('SELECT id, uploaded_by, filename from file') as $row) {
        $name = explode(" ", $row['uploaded_by']);
        $first_name = $name[0];
        $last_name = $name[1];

        $profile = $newDb->prepare("SELECT id FROM profiles WHERE first_name = :first_name");
        $profile->bindParam(':first_name', $first_name);
        $profile->execute();
        $data = $profile->fetchAll();


        $file = $newDb->prepare("INSERT INTO files (id, filename, User_id) VALUES (:id, :filename, :User_id)");
        $file->bindParam(':id', $row['id']);
        $file->bindParam(':filename', $row['filename']);
        $file->bindParam(':User_id', $data['id']);
        $file->execute();
    }

    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

So I try to insert the data from the old database to the new one but I get a error :

```
Error!: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'User_id' cannot be null
```

when I try to insert the files from the old database to the new one. When i print_r the user_id i get a

```
 Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/vagrant/HassanKebabStore/newDatabase/index.php on line 36
```

If someone can help me I would appreciate it very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because it cant found the user_id variable.
Just like you have:

```
    $file->bindParam(':id', $row['id']);
    $file->bindParam(':filename', $row['filename']);
```

You need to change the id of the user data to user_id

```
    $file->bindParam(':User_id', $data['User_id']);
```

I think this is the fix

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your query results are not the ones you expect. First of all i'd put a `print_r($row)` to check that the row has the values you are using later. I guess theses values are empty (at least 'id').

```
...
foreach ($oldDb->query('SELECT id, email, password, name, street, house_number, postcode, role from users') as $row) {

    print_r($row);

    $userId = $row['id'];
...
```

Could you give us the results please?